# How to pass data between already opened activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities:

1. Setup
2. Test
3. Result

After I passed a test and got a result, I need to get back to `SetupActivity` with the saved result (it's a custom class). To keep its state saved, I don't apply the `finish()` method on SetupActivity before opening TestActivity but then I have a problem with passing my results to the SetupActivity because I can't make an intent to already opened activity. So what is the best way to solve this problem? I need to keep the instance of SetupActivity saved and at the same time, I need to pass the data to this activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharedPreferences to save the data in one activity and then get it in the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dependency Injection, you can send your data easily. If you don't use it, try below.

Pass from First Activity

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("key", "value")
startActivity(intent)
```

Get in Second Activity

```
val value = intent.getStringExtra("key")
Suggestion
```

Always put keys in constant file for more managed way.

```
companion object {
    val KEY = "key"
}
```

2. way is using a Singleton class:

   ```
   object UserModelSingleton {  var KEY: String? = null}
   ```